# Filtering words with numbers and retrieving 2-grams and 1-grams with Lucene

Tags: java, lucene, tokenize, n-gram

I'm trying to use Lucene (5.5.0) for some string tokenization (no indexing).
I need to:

1. Completely remove words containing numbers, so for example words like log4j should be removed from the string
2. I would like to split my string into one word terms and also into 2-Grams terms, so for example: "tie a yellow ribbon" should be tokenized to the following terms: "tie", "yellow", "ribbon", "yellow ribbon". Note that "tie yellow" is not a term since it has a stop word in the middle

Are these possible to do with Lucene? If so how?

What I've done so far:

- Regarding removing words containing numbers I encountered WordDelimetedFilter which is not good since in the documentation it shows it splits the word SD500 into "SD" and "500" while I want to remove it entirely. I also found a NumericPayloadTokenFilter which looks promising (by the name) but I'm having some issues understanding how to work with it
- Regarding the 2Grams and 1Grams, I've found several examples of how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433670/java-lucene-ngramtokenizer), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29103144/how-to-have-ngram-tokenizer-in-lucene-5-0) and in the [NGramTokenizer documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ngram/NGramTokenFilter.html) however they all seem to be working on chars and not on words which is what I need

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On requirement 1:  I'm not aware of anything that does this, out of the box.  `NumericPayloadTokenFilter` is *definitely* not what you need.  You will probably need to create your own token filter to do this.

On requirement 2:  NGrams, in Lucene parlance, are generally based on characters.  What you want is [ShingleFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/shingle/ShingleFilter.html), which combines tokens.  It will create shingles at stop words, like:  `tie _` and `_ yellow`, where _ is a generic filler token.

Comment: Writing the filter was fairly easy to get done by looking at some filters examples. Thanks for your answer